# Updater process ended with ERROR: 1 on Mi A2 (jasmine_sprout)

Tags: twrp

I want to install Ubuntu Touch on my phone and one of the steps is to install a specific build of Android 9 on the phone. When I try to do this I get this error in OrangeFox Recovery:

```
Flashing A/B zip to inactive slot: A
Updater process ended with ERROR: 1
To flash additional zips, please reboot recovery to switch to the updated slot.
Error installing ZIP file '/jasmine_sprout_stock_android9.zip'
```

In TWRP everything happens without errors, but when the phone reboots it goes into recovery or constantly reboots.

I have successfully installed Ubuntu Touch on this phone before without any problems, this is the first time this has happened to me.

Things I've already tried:

- Downloading the firmware again
- Erasing all partitions
- Changing the file system to ext4 for /system and /data
- Reinstalling OrangeFox Recovery
- Installing the latest stock firmware via Fastboot

Here is a link to the installation guide: https://devices.ubuntu-touch.io/device/jasmine-sprout/release/xenial
Here is a link to the Android 9 build itself: https://github.com/ubports-xiaomi-sdm660/artifacts/releases/download/v0.1/jasmine_sprout_stock_android9.zip